# How to decode SCC file?

Tags: php, file, parsing, decode

After severals researches on Google and Github, I'm coming here to ask for help.

I'm creating a SCC file parser in order to convert it to a DFXP file.
Nevertheless, I can't find any information to obtain plain text from SCC file.

SCC file example :

```
Scenarist_SCC V1.0

00:59:59;26 9420 9420 94f2 94f2 ad20 cd61 e973 206e ef6e 2c20 e3a7 e573 f420 e661 75f8 ae80 942c 942c 942f 942f

01:00:01;22 9420 9420 9454 9454 9723 9723 4aa7 61e9 2061 e96d dc2c 94f2 94f2 97a2 97a2 e3a7 e573 f420 f4f2 91ba 91ba 7320 64e9 e6e6 dcf2 e56e f4ae 942c 942c 942f 942f

01:00:04;07 9420 9420 94d0 94d0 97a1 97a1 4aa7 61e9 2061 e96d dc20 64e5 75f8 20ef 7520 f4f2 efe9 7320 e6e5 6d6d e573 94f4 94f4 97a2 97a2 6461 6e73 206d 6120 76e9 e5ae 942c 942c 942f 942f
```

Its translation in plain text is :

```
Dans une pièce à la lumière tamisée, un homme en complet assis sur un   fauteuil s'adresse à un interlocuteur hors champ.

HOMME : Mais non, c'est faux. J'ai aimé, c'est très différent. J'ai aimé deux ou trois femmes dans ma vie. Enfin, disons trois ou quatre. J'ai vécu avec elles des périodes très longues, qui ont duré plusieurs années. Je ne les ai peut-être pas aimées follement...

Il semble pensif.
```

Comment: Why did you put  in the "version control" tag in the original question?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's Stack Overflow's fault: [tag:scc] is marked as a synonym of [tag:version-control], but  unsurprisingly the TLA has other uses, as in this case.

Comment: @IMSoP Ah, yes, people should check the meaning of the tags beforehand, but I agree that SO doesn't help with getting the right ones. Maybe they should display the synonym and description in advance. One of my semi-regular things is to rename all the mistagged [tag:signature] questions to [tag:digital-signature] and to remove the tag from the questions about email signatures altogether.

Answer (score 1):

an app already exists for this called SCC Caption Decoder for Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain plain text, you need to convert hex codes to letters.

```
Example: ad20 cd61 >>translates to>> "- Ma"
ad - "-"
20 - " " // space
cd - "M"
61 - "a"
```

Also, there are control codes like 9420. That are not text.

To find the translation table for letters, check here: https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles/blob/v1.0.14/src/Code/Converters/SccConverter.php#L843

Also a bit higher there is a table for control codes, that you can skip when parsing just text.

---

Or you can use a [library](https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles) that would convert SCC to DFXP

```
php subtitles.phar input.scc output.dfxp
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but you could use a library to convert the SCC file into a human readable subtitle file format like SubRip (.srt). I don't know of any PHP library to perform this task however.

I have used CCASDI.exe (Windows Executable) from this page successfully: http://www.theneitherworld.com/mcpoodle/SCC_TOOLS/DOCS/SCC_TOOLS.HTML#ccasdi

And I have also used this JavaScript library: https://github.com/jasonrojas/node-captions

I know of other people who have been using this Python tool: https://github.com/bdon/pycaption

Comment: This is a good answer. You should also add that documentation is available in the US Code of Regulations, Title 47, Section 15.119. https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CFR-2009-title47-vol1/pdf/CFR-2009-title47-vol1-sec15-119.pdf

Answer (score -3):

from pycaption import SCCReader
input = '00:00:03:13 9420 9454 5bcb 45d9 c24f c152 c449 cec7 94f2 c1ce c420 434f cdd0 d554 4552 20ce 4f49 d345 d35d'
contents = SCCReader().read(input.decode('utf-8'))
contents.get_captions('en-US')

Comment: from pycaption import SCCReader

file=open('div.scc','r')
data=file.read()
contents=SCCReader().read(data.decode('utf-8'))
input=contents.get_captions('en-US')
print(input)

Comment: Please spend some more time on formatting your answer. It is very hard to read at this state.

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does that code solve any problem? To me, that does not look like PHP code after all

Comment: This is Python code but the question asks about PHP